# Script firefox to print to PDF

Tags: firefox, pdf, printing, script, ebook

I like finetuning my ebooks to make them look really nice, and since my e-reader has limited justification capabilities (that is, it's really bad at justifying text), I usually print my html books as PDF, with specific page size settings.

I've set up a specific PDF Creator printer with correct default settings (page size notably), and set up firefox to print with the correct margins. Since some books use LaTeX code in the html contents, I use jsMath to produce scalable math. Using a latex-to html converter is not an option, because pdflatex generates whitespaces which are not compatible with the way my e-readr detects words boundaries, and hence it disables most useful functions such as dictionary lookups and the like.

So my usual workflow is

- Open the HTML book in firefox
- Wait for jsMath to complete
- Print as PDF

Is there a way to script firefox so that I only have one command to launch. Ideally I'd type something like

```
firefox print-after-waiting-for-script-completion path-to-html-page
```

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a macros plug-in called iMacros available for Firefox. Just search for it in Tools > Add-ons. I've never used it, so I can't tell you how well it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) add-on for Firefox.

> iMacros is extremely versatile and can be combined with other extensions such as Greasemonkey, Web Developer, Firebug, Stylish, Download Statusbar, NoScript, PDF Download, Foxmarks, Fasterfox, All-in-One Sidebar, Megaupload, Foxyproxy, Flashblock and Adblock.

I'll later see if I can create a macro for your particular case. But you can try too using Macro Recorder feature and getting some help in http://forum.iopus.com